# python BeautifulSoup - how to detect file attachment in target

Tags: python, file, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a bot in python that searches google for results.
Then, through BeautifulSoup, it goes to every website and looks for something there.

The problem is that if a given page in the results is, for example:
https://somepage.com/attachfile.pdf
then python automatically downloads this attachment to the server.

I want to detect if there is a file in the target link and if so, I want to block the download of the file to the server, how to do it?

My code:

```
            driver.get(h.a.get('href'))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
            source_text = soup(text=re.compile(wp_string))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
                    content_type = requests.head(h.a.get('href')).headers["Content-Type"]
                
                if "text/html" in content_type:
                    logging.info("Correct URL response Header Content-Type:" + content_type)
                else:
                    logging.info("InCorrect URL response Header Content-Type:" + content_type)    
                    logging.info("break from for")
                    break
                
                driver.get(h.a.get('href')) # it downloads the file if exists
```